# NSOpenPanel() Domain Errors

Tags: swift, xcode, nsopenpanel

Call to OpenPanel() produces below debug errors in Xcode 10.1, Swift 4.2. Oddly, that path volume and user name is a path that's from years ago and isn't on anything I have now. Doesn't seem to affect the program but I'm wondering if there's a way to fix it.

```
@IBAction func addSlide(_ sender: NSButton) {
    let insertAtIndexPath = collectionView.selectionIndexPaths.first!
    let openPanel = NSOpenPanel()
    openPanel.canChooseDirectories = false
    openPanel.canChooseFiles = true
    openPanel.allowsMultipleSelection = true
    openPanel.allowedFileTypes = ["public.image"]
    openPanel.beginSheetModal(for: self.view.window!) { (response) in
        guard response.rawValue == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton
        else {
          return
        }
        self.inserAtIndexPathFromURLs(urls: openPanel.urls as [NSURL], atIndexPath: insertAtIndexPath as NSIndexPath)
    } 
}
```

2020-01-04 16:20:46.561448-0600 SlidesPro[15750:7808376] [default] Faild to get owner UUID for url: file:///Volumes/Bare%20OS%20X%20Yosemitte%20Bootup%20 error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “Bare OS X Yosemitte Bootup ” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSURL=file:///Volumes/Bare%20OS%20X%20Yosemitte%20Bootup%20, NSFilePath=/Volumes/Bare OS X Yosemitte Bootup , NSUnderlyingError=0x61000004d500 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}

2020-01-04 16:20:46.561766-0600 SlidesPro[15750:7808376] [default] Faild to get owner UUID for url: file:///Volumes/Bare%20OS%20X%20Yosemitte%20Bootup%20 error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “Bare OS X Yosemitte Bootup ” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSURL=file:///Volumes/Bare%20OS%20X%20Yosemitte%20Bootup%20, NSFilePath=/Volumes/Bare OS X Yosemitte Bootup , NSUnderlyingError=0x60c00004cb70 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}

2020-01-04 16:20:46.562065-0600 SlidesPro[15750:7808376] [default] Faild to get owner UUID for url: file:///Users/macuser/Public error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “Public” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSURL=file:///Users/macuser/Public, NSFilePath=/Users/macuser/Public, NSUnderlyingError=0x61000004d1d0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}

2020-01-04 16:20:46.562316-0600 SlidesPro[15750:7808376] [default] Faild to get owner UUID for url: file:///Users/macuser/Public error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “Public” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSURL=file:///Users/macuser/Public, NSFilePath=/Users/macuser/Public, NSUnderlyingError=0x61000004d3b0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}

Update: 1-5-20 I added an app sandbox entitlement then turned off entitlements after rerunning. No more errors in the debug pane. I don't know why but it worked.

Comment: What is the following line for?  self.inserAtIndexPathFromURLs(urls: openPanel.urls as [NSURL], atIndexPath: insertAtIndexPath as NSIndexPath)

Comment: It's for adding an image selected from a folder into a collectionview at a place chosen by the user in the view window. It has no bearing on the issue at hand. The errors occur immediately when NSOpenPanel is called but doesn't affect the functioning . Everything in the project works as expected.

Comment: You are probably getting an error because you force-unwrap a variable on the 2nd line, which you use the said line earlier.

Comment: Did you check the preferences file(s)?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. If you're talking about Xcode preferences, there's nothing there to indicate a cause for this. There's nothing in the info.plist file or build settings either. Kind of wondering what this UserInfo =  thing is and where it comes from. I don't see any problems with running the app so maybe I can just ignore this. Sometimes you'll get debugging messages that can safely be ignored. Another user on SO mentioned a problem similar to mine but there was no answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recompiling old cocoa app without sandbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51220531/recompiling-old-cocoa-app-without-sandbox)

Comment: Thanks that was very helpful! I updated my question even if I didn't quite understand  why it worked 